# Android AlarmManager, how to send intent every 3 days?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using this to launch an Intent to trigger a reciever...

How would i go about setting this so that every 3 days it sends the intent??

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(alarm);

    Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Aintent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 3 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: What do you mean? Calendar code defines when it should start first time. And interval defines how frequently it should be repeated.